A Crossworm Puzzle

crossworm (noun) - A song that gets stuck in one's crossword puzzle.
See also: earworm

You know how it is - one moment, you've got a song stuck in your head; the next, it's stuck in your crossword puzzle too!

TASK: Fit the answers to the thematically-worded clues below into the crossword puzzle, then find the name of the song that's responsible for the theme, lurking as a long 'worm' of orthogonally-adjacent letters somewhere in the grid!


Solve on Penpa+
Across:
1. South Koreans Idol-ised on teenage bedroom posters
4. Question asked when bread is burned in temperamental toasters
7. Local and habitual spasmodic muscle motion
9. Adjective for something that's been given a promotion?
10. Symbol used to indicate a 'sharp' by famed composers
12. Coin pre-dating Euro found 'tween cushions of French sofas?
13. Double act or pairing like Bellatrix and Rodolphus
14. Sportswear brand that's popular with tennis stars and golfers
17. Broad sash worn around the waist of Japanese kimonos
18. Noise made by a dog to get attention from their owners?
19. Mesozoic BLANK - a time of dinosaurs ferocious
20. Medical professional who makes a diagnosis
21. Petrol for Americans to put inside their motors
23. Disembarked from ferries, trains or even roller coasters
25. Sprite deemed uncontrollable, who'd mischievously roast us
28. Places where wild animals might live, quite safe from poachers
30. Angle at which vessels lean whilst floating on the oceans
31. Formally eject from school (for causing a commotion?)
32. High priest in the Bible who considered Hannah stotious
33. Very cold or slippery on roads for cars and coaches
34. Um diddle-iddle-iddle, um diddle… what??
Down:
2. Grassy lawn material laid waste by moles and gophers
3. Place to get a 'pedi' (after taking off your loafers)
4. Oxon town where 'BoJo' was elected by the voters
5. Oceanic predator, the scourge of seals and boaters
6. UN team with target to defeat tuberculosis
7. Just a teeny-tiny bit you might not even notice
8. Options to select between (like who to pick for POTUS)
11. Underwater vessel that sails far beneath the floaters
12. Breakable or brittle-boned, with osteoporosis
15. Saying none of these "...or ands or buts" means "No excuses"
16. This comprises lots of stars (and sometimes supernovas)
17. Cricket World Cup match format that lasts just fifty overs
22. 'Friend' to fellow who might say their driver is 'un chauffeur'
23. ____ Guinness, who in David Lean films gained acclaimed exposure
24. Three-point score by player from the San Antonio Spurs?
26. Clinical prediction rule for patients with pneumonias
27. Bladder problem caused by E. coli or Pseudomonas
29. Hoppy beers like Brewdog's 'Punk' - not lagers like Coronas

The song is

SUPERCALIFRAGILISTICEXPIALIDOCIOUS!!


The crossword solves as follows:

 

With the answers being:

Across:

1. South Koreans Idol-ised on teenage bedroom posters - BTS
4. Question asked when bread is burned in temperamental toasters - HOW
7. Local and habitual spasmodic muscle motion - TIC
9. Adjective for something that's been given a promotion? - SUPER
10. Symbol used to indicate a 'sharp' by famed composers - HASH
12. Coin pre-dating Euro found 'tween cushions of French sofas? - FRANC
13. Double act or pairing like Bellatrix and Rodolphus - DUO
14. Sportswear brand that's popular with tennis stars and golfers - FILA
17. Broad sash worn around the waist of Japanese kimonos - OBI
18. Noise made by a dog to get attention from their owners? - ARF
19. Mesozoic BLANK - a time of dinosaurs ferocious - ERA
20. Medical professional who makes a diagnosis - DOC
21. Petrol for Americans to put inside their motors - GAS
23. Disembarked from ferries, trains or even roller coasters -  ALIT
25. Sprite deemed uncontrollable, who'd mischievously roast us - IMP
28. Places where wild animals might live, quite safe from poachers - LAIRS
30. Angle at which vessels lean whilst floating on the oceans - LIST
31. Formally eject from school (for causing a commotion?) - EXPEL
32. High priest in the Bible who considered Hannah stotious - ELI
33. Very cold or slippery on roads for cars and coaches - ICY
34. Um diddle-iddle-iddle, um diddle… what?? - AYE

Down:

2. Grassy lawn material laid waste by moles and gophers - TURF
3. Place to get a 'pedi' (after taking off your loafers) - SPA
4. Oxon town where 'BoJo' was elected by the voters - HENLEY
5. Oceanic predator, the scourge of seals and boaters - ORCA
6. UN team with target to defeat tuberculosis - WHO
7. Just a teeny-tiny bit you might not even notice - TAD
8. Options to select between (like who to pick for POTUS) - CHOICES
11. Underwater vessel that sails far beneath the floaters - SUB
12. Breakable or brittle-boned, with osteoporosis - FRAGILE
15. Saying none of these "...or ands or buts" means "No excuses" - IFS
16. This comprises lots of stars (and sometimes supernovas) - GALAXY
17. Cricket World Cup match format that lasts just fifty overs - ODI
22. 'Friend' to fellow who might say their driver is 'un chauffeur' - AMI
23. ____ Guinness, who in David Lean films gained acclaimed exposure - ALEC
24. Three-point score by player from the San Antonio Spurs? - TREY
26. Clinical prediction rule for patients with pneumonias - PSI
27. Bladder problem caused by E. coli or Pseudomonas - UTI
29. Hoppy beers like Brewdog's 'Punk' - not lagers like Coronas - IPA

And then we can see the following traced through the grid:

 

The song SUPERCALIFRAGILISTICEXPIALIDOCIOUS can be traced through the grid!

This is further hinted at by 34 across, as it is a lyric of the song!

Furthermore:

Every single clue rhymes with the song name!


You've cracked it :) It's possible, however, (although I didn't state it explicitly) to spell it out without passing through any walls (which will also correct one typo in your worm... as much as you can have a typo in a completely fictitious word...!).

@Stiv ah yep, I see the path, will update! (I'm still impressed you managed to find so many words that rhymed!)

And not only the rhymes - the meter fits too!

It took longer to come up with the wording of the clues themselves than it did to do the rest of the puzzle creation! A lot of fun to make though - and I guarantee that some folks will find themselves singing their way through the clues :)

Have just added a Wiki link for reference and amended one clash between your clue answers and the grid (the last one). The checkmark is yours :) Feel free to add any other links you think people might need for answering trickier clues. Thanks for solving!

@Stiv thanks for the catch, wasn't sure if it was supposed to be ayy or aye but knew it didn't really matter, will go through a bit later and add some links for some of the more obscure clues!

The word oxon might also benefit from an explanation @Stiv. Although not originally from here, I've been living in the UK for almost 10 years now and I still had no clue what that was.
